# How do I get all cookies active on the current page in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a google chrome extension and want access to all cookies that are included in the current request. I have the cleaned domain in the variable `domain`

So far the (relevant) code is

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: domain}, showCookies)
```

Which works in getting the cookies that match at least the entire domain, but the same origion- policy means that if `domain` is gist.github.com  then any cookies set on .github.com are also included in a request - but how do I get those "extra" cookies for any given domain?

My first idea was to cut of the part upto the first dot, but that does not seem correct.

Comment: What if you use `url` instead of `domain`?

Comment: @Xan Doesn't work, it just gives me (what appears to be) all the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the same origion- policy means that if domain is gist.github.com then any cookies set on .github.com are also included in a request"

That's not really true. gist.github.com is a distinct origin from github.com and cookies aren't automatically included in the request. Something else is going on.

That said, if you
- set the domain to just "github.com" you'll get all github's cookies and gist.github's cookies and you can filter for yourself.